# Weird bug when passing from $_GET to $_SESSION

Tags: javascript, php, session, urlencode

I'm using Opauth to authenticate users to my site via Twitter/Facebook.

When they are leaving the site I am saving a redirect url to the session
so that when they come back to the site they are redirected to the page
they were previously viewing.

I'm having this extremely weird bug where if the session variable is saved in any way from the get variable, when I'm redirected the session variable is blank.

If I do this it works and the var is correct when I'm
redirected back from twitter/facebook:

```
$_SESSION['r'] = 'asdf';
```

If I do any of the following, it comes back as NULL or empty string:

```
$_SESSION['r'] = $_GET['r'];
$_SESSION['r'] = base64_encode($_GET['r']);
$_SESSION['r'] = urlencode($_GET['r']);
```

I have also tried every possible way of encoding it in the javascript before it gets to the url param...

```
window.location.href = '/opauth/twitter?r=' + btoa(window.location.pathname);
```

This is extremely frustrating and if anyone could help me I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Just a quick sanity check, you are calling `session_start` on that page, correct?

Comment: Print `$_GET['r']` before you set it, odds are its actually not set when that code is getting evaluated.

Comment: are you have `session_start();` code on the pages? and also check that `$_GET` have values or not?

Comment: ^^ Not just on this page, but `session_start()` must be present on _every_ script which reads or writes `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Try with `POST` or `REQUEST`

Comment: I have tried all obvious things. Session start is being called. $_GET['r'] definitely has a value. It even get's set to the session if you print $_SESSION['r'] after it's set.

Comment: `$_GET['r'] definitely has a value` why don't you try to check by printing it out and tell what value it have?show that value to us.Thanks

Comment: I have checked... It is exactly as expected... /opauth/twitter?r=L3Byb2ZpbGUvdmFycmljay8= prints out L3Byb2ZpbGUvdmFycmljay8=

Comment: Make sure none of the pages are warning "Headers already sent" when you call `session_start()`.

Comment: try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` on each page at top after starting `<?php` tag and check the exact error.

Comment: Turning on all error reporting has thrown up some stuff. Stupid me, shoulda thought of that before. I'll do some more investigating in a bit and get back to you guys. No need for more tips at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out not to be at all to with
the way the request or urlencode work.

It was purely because although we end up
on callback.php when coming back from Twitter/Facebook
we have had to have gone through index.php.

This means that the logic that was setting the
$_SESSION variable was also clearing it as
there was no $_GET variable set when coming
back from Twitter.

Sorry for this confused, misdirecting question.